# Pancake Sorting Graph Recursive Definition

Tags: graphs, sorting, recursion

I'm having trouble understanding exactly how the graph for Pn (where n = number of pancakes) is defined recursively for n>= 4. I can see obviously that, in the case of n=4, there will be 4 rough copies of the graph where n=3 with additions of 4 in certain places (where, and how is this defined?). But these copies aren't exact, and I can't find any detail on Wikipedia except for that it is indeed recursively defined. I'm asking with a view possibly to be able to generate a graph algorithmically for n>=4 recursively.

Here is a graph for n=4 (so there are 4! / 24 possible configurations of pancakes, and thus 24 nodes in the graph). Here it is for n=4, on this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_graph.

See this Wikipedia article for more on Pancake Sorting - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more context and define your terms/notation.  I don't know what Pn is supposed to represent; can you edit your question to make it self-contained?

Comment: Have added new links to the post.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_graph):

> The pancake graph $P_n$ or $n$-pancake graph is a graph whose vertices
>   are the permutations of $n$ symbols from 1 to $n$ and its edges are given
>   between permutations transitive by prefix reversals.

$P_n$ can be constructed from $n$ copies of $P_{n-1}$. We can construct $P_4$ from $P_3$, which looks like:

[image]

We start by making 4 copies of $P_3$ and numbering them 1 through $n$. Let's look at one particular copy and call it copy $i$. For each node in that instance of $P_{n-1}$, replace $i$ with $n$ and then append $i$ to the end of each sequence. For the $n$th copy, we don't have to do any replacing and can simply append $n$ to the end.

For example, for the 2nd copy of $P_3$ we'll first replace all the 2s with 4s and then append 2 to the end:

[image]

We now have a graph with nodes for all of the permutations of the elements from 1 to 4, and we have edges between sequences that can be transformed into one another by flipping a proper prefix. Edges from $P_{n-1}$ are still valid in $P_n$ because the only thing we've done is relabel and append a suffix.

Now go through each node and add a new edge going to the node corresponding to flipping the entire sequence. For example, (4,3,1,2) gets connected to (2,1,3,4), (1,2,3,4) gets connected to (4,3,2,1), etc.

The final graph for $P_4$ as shown in the Wikipedia article linked in the question looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble understanding exactly how the graph for Pn (where n = number of pancakes) is defined recursively for n>= 4. ... I'm asking with a view possibly to be able to generate a graph algorithmically for n>=4 recursively.

A webpage providing source code for pancake sorting in over 50 different languages is here: "[Sorting algorithms/Pancake sort](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Pancake_sort)" at the [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) website.

See the paper: "[Some relations on prefix reversal generators of the symmetric and hyperoctahedral group](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01760)" (Jun 7 2018), by Saúl A. Blanco and Charles Buehrle:

> Page 1: "The best upper and lower bound known today for the general case appeared in `[5]` and `[12]`, respectively. Combined, one has that
>
> $$15 \left \lfloor \frac{n}{14} \right \rfloor \le f(n) \le \frac{18n}{11} + O(1).$$
>
> Computing the pancake number for a given n is a complicated task. To our knowledge, the exact value of f(n) is only known for 1 ≤ n ≤ 19 (see `[2, 6, 7, 12, 18]`). In fact, determining the minimum number needed to sort a stack of pancakes is an NP-hard problem [[4](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0434)], though 2-approximation algorithms exists [[10](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2016/01/15/036814)].
>
> `[2]` Shogo Asai, Yuusuke Kounoike, Yuji Shinano, and Keiichi Kaneko. Computing the Diameter of 17-Pancake Graph Using a PC Cluster, pages 1114–1124. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2006.
>
> `[4]` Laurent Bulteau, Guillaume Fertin, and Irena Rusu. [Pancake flipping is hard](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0434). J. Comput. System Sci., 81(8):1556–1574, 2015.
>
> `[5]` B. Chitturi, W. Fahle, Z. Meng, L. Morales, C. O. Shields, I. H. Sudborough, and W. Voit. An (18/11)$n$ upper bound for sorting by prefix reversals. Theoret. Comput. Sci., 410(36):3372–3390, 2009.
>
> `[6]` Josef Cibulka. On average and highest number of flips in pancake sorting. Theoret. Comput. Sci., 412(8-10):822–834, 2011.
>
> `[7]` David S. Cohen and Manuel Blum. On the problem of sorting burnt pancakes. Discrete Appl. Math., 61(2):105–120, 1995.
>
> `[10]` Johannes Fischer and Simon W. Ginzinger. [A 2-Approximation Algorithm for Sorting by Prefix Reversals](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/early/2016/01/15/036814), pages 415–425. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2005.
>
> `[12]` Mohammad H. Heydari and I. Hal Sudborough. On the diameter of the pancake network. J. Algorithms, 25(1):67–94, 1997.
>
> `[18]` Y. Kounoike, K. Kaneko, and Y. Shinano. Computing the diameters of 14- and 15-pancake graphs. In 8th International Symposium on Parallel Architectures, Algorithms and Networks (ISPAN’05), Dec 2005.

The [Rosetta Code C++ implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Pancake_sort#C.2B.2B) is:

```c++
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

// pancake sort template (calls predicate to determine order)
template <typename BidIt, typename Pred>
void pancake_sort(BidIt first, BidIt last, Pred order)
{
    if (std::distance(first, last) < 2) return; // no sort needed

    for (; first != last; --last)
    {
        BidIt mid = std::max_element(first, last, order);
        if (mid == last - 1)
        {
            continue; // no flips needed
        }
        if (first != mid)
        {
            std::reverse(first, mid + 1); // flip element to front
        }
        std::reverse(first, last); // flip front to final position
    }
}

// pancake sort template (ascending order)
template <typename BidIt>
void pancake_sort(BidIt first, BidIt last)
{
    pancake_sort(first, last, std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<BidIt>::value_type>());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        data.push_back(i); // generate test data
    }
    std::random_shuffle(data.begin(), data.end()); // scramble data

    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";

    pancake_sort(data.begin(), data.end()); // ascending pancake sort

    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 4 10 11 15 14 16 17 1 6 9 3 7 19 2 0 12 5 18 13 8
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
> ```